# YouTube Live Streaming API V3 when Insert Live Broadcast scheduledStartTime not Work Properly

Tags: google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have inserted YouTube live broadcast using PHP client library live broad cast inserted successfully but scheduledStartTime is not showing properly according to my timezone when i verify it by clicking on event link on live dashboard page.

My time zone is GMT+05:00 and country is Pakistan.
I have scheduled event at 2019-01-21 05:50 PM. But on event page it shows "Starts January 21, 2019 at 4:50 AM (PST)" when I click edit it shows wrong country and time zone like that "United States (GMT -08:00) Pacific".

Please help me how i can fix it so that it shows correct schedule time on event listing page and correct country, schedule time and time zone on edit event page.

Please see below my code while inserting live broadcast object using php client library.

```
$tz = 'Asia/Karachi';
$timestamp = strtotime("2019-01-21 17:50:00");
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($tz));
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp
$schedule_time = $dt->format('c');

$broadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
$broadcastSnippet->setTitle('Test Schedule Event');
$broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($schedule_time);
```

It should shows correct schedule time on event listing page like "Starts January 21, 2019 at 5:50 PM (GMT+5)" and on edit event page it should show correct country, schedule time and time zone like that "Pakistan (GMT +05:00) Karachi".

Comment: Can any one help me on this i am stuck to this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are specifying the start time in ISO 8601 format and that the time-zone information is included in the string.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.scheduledStartTime